# How to use ansible pip executable `/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip`?

Tags: pip, ansible

My playbook

```yaml
- name: "Install python package 'requests'"
  pip:
    name: requests
    executable: /usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip
  become: yes
```

Which errors with:

```
TASK [Install python package 'requests'] **************************
fatal: [integration]: FAILED! => changed=false
  cmd: '''/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip'' install requests'
  msg: '[Errno 2] No such file or directory'
  rc: 2
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
```

I didn't install `pip` or `pip3` in the managed node, that is why `executable: pip3` would not work.

Comment: Just an FYI: your executable value should only be e.g. `pip3.3`, do not include `-m pip` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/easy_install_module.html#notes), the recommended way to achieve this is to use the [`easy_install` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/easy_install_module.html) in order to make pip available on the managed node, and then, use the builtin module `pip`, normally.

> Please note that the `easy_install` module can only install Python libraries. Thus this module is not able to remove libraries. It is generally recommended to use the `ansible.builtin.pip` module which you can first install using `community.general.easy_install`.

So, in a two tasks:

```yaml
- name: Install or update pip
  community.general.easy_install:
    name: pip
    state: latest
  become: yes

- name: Install python package 'requests'
  ansible.builtin.pip:
    name: requests
  become: yes
```

Comment: Wouldn't a better approach be to install the python3-pip package? And then just update pip.

Comment: Like Ansible, the recommended way to install pip Is not through the package manager: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/. For the same reasons, also, package managers are lagging behind in terms of version. So, instead of installing it the wrong way then update it, why not installing it in a way that will install it to the most recent version directly?

Comment: You're right, the best way is to install the correct version of the dependency.